# QNX pthread_mutex_lock causing deadlock error ( 45 = EDEADLK )

Tags: c++, queue, mutex, deadlock, qnx

I am implementing an asynchronous log writing mechanism for my project's multithreaded application. Below is the partial code of the part  where the error occurs.

```
void CTraceFileWriterThread::run() 
{
    bool fShoudIRun = shouldThreadsRun();  //  Some global function which decided if operations need to stop. Not really relevant here. Assume "true" value.

    while(fShoudIRun)
    {
      std::string nextMessage = fetchNext();
      if( !nextMessage.empty() )
      {
          process(nextMessage);
      }
      else
      {
          fShoudIRun = shouldThreadsRun();
          condVarTraceWriter.wait();
      }
    }
 }

//This is the consumer. This is in my thread with lower priority
std::string CTraceFileWriterThread::fetchNext() 
{
    // When there are a lot of logs, I mean A LOT, I believe the 
    // control stays in this function for a long time and an other 
    // thread calling the "add" function is not able to acquire the lock
    // since its held here.

    std::string message;

    if( !writeQueue.empty() )
    {
      writeQueueMutex.lock();        // Obj of our wrapper around pthread_mutex_lock 
      message = writeQueue.front();  
      writeQueue.pop();              // std::queue
      writeQueueMutex.unLock() ;
    }
    return message;
}




//  This is the producer and is called from multiple threads.
void CTraceFileWriterThread::add( std::string outputString ) {

if ( !outputString.empty() )
{
    // crashes here while trying to acquire the lock when there are lots of
    // logs in prod systems.

    writeQueueMutex.lock();
    const size_t writeQueueSize = writeQueue.size();

    if ( writeQueueSize == maximumWriteQueueCapacity )
    {
        outputString.append ("\n queue full, discarding traces, traces are incomplete" );
    }

    if ( writeQueueSize <= maximumWriteQueueCapacity )
    {
        bool wasEmpty = writeQueue.empty();
        writeQueue.push(outputString);



        condVarTraceWriter.post(); // will be waiting in a function which calls "fetchNext"

    }
    writeQueueMutex.unLock();

}


int wrapperMutex::lock() {
//#[ operation lock()

 int iRetval;
 int iRetry = 10;

 do
 {
    //
    iRetry--;
    tRfcErrno = pthread_mutex_lock (&tMutex);
    if ( (tRfcErrno == EINTR) || (tRfcErrno == EAGAIN) )
    {
        iRetval = RFC_ERROR;    
        (void)sched_yield();
    }
    else if (tRfcErrno != EOK)
    {
        iRetval = RFC_ERROR;    
        iRetry = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        iRetval = RFC_OK;    
        iRetry = 0;
    }
 } while (iRetry > 0);

 return iRetval;


//#]
```

}

I generated the core dump and analysed it with GDB and here are some findings

1. Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
2. "Errno=45" at the add function where I am trying to acquire the lock. The wrapper we have around pthread_mutex_lock tries to acquire the lock for around 10 times before it gives up.

The code works fine when there are fewer logs. Also, we do not have C++11 or further and hence restricted to mutex of QNX. Any help is appreciated as I am looking at this issue for over a month with little progress. Please ask if anymore info is required.

Comment: We need to see any code that touches the queue, mutex, or condvar. Also, if it's safe to call `writeQueue.empty` without the mutex, what does the mutex protect exactly?

Comment: I have added an other relevant function. Only the empty() function was called without the mutex lock. The thought was that it wasn't worth it to make the other higher prio threads wait in the "add" function even when the queue was empty. It doesn't really matter if the queue is deemed empty when an entry is getting written since the log writing operation is of low priority and can wait a few milliseconds.

Comment: What type is `writeQueue`? If it's a `std::queue`, you *can't* call `empty` without the mutex. The results of doing so are unpredictable and corruption could result. Also, when `run` calls `condVarTraceWriter.wait()`, what exactly is it waiting for and how does it know that what it's waiting for hasn't already happened? Can you paste the code for the wrapper? Where exactly did the segfault happen?

Comment: You need to provide the relevant code for the types associated with `writeQueueMutex` and `writeQueue`.  Also, you state `"The wrapper we have around pthread_mutex_lock tries to acquire the lock for around 10 times before it gives up"` -- what do you mean by "gives up"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes it is a std::queue i will see if i can enclose the empty() function within the mutex. Thanks for that. If you see there is a call to condVarTraceWriter.post() which specifies when to stop waiting. I have pasted the wrapper function code. Unfortunately, even multiple core dump analysis did not specify any consistent line where the seg fault occured. The common factor was that it happened very soon after the deadlock errors occured.

Comment: @G.M. I have added the relevant wrapper code which should answer your question

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and the deadlock error occurs at the beginning of add function. I have added comments there.

Comment: You never check the value returned by `wrapperMutex::lock` so it's quite possible you're accessing a non-threadsafe queue *without* the lock in place.  Also, what type of mutex is `tMutex` -- normal, recursive, something else?  If it's a normal pthread mutex then a deadlock might suggest a thread is trying to relock a mutex that it already owns.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please elaborate on that. Right now, I wait when the queue is empty and notify when something populates in it

Comment: @G.M.I will have to check more on your first point but it makes sense. and yes, it is a normal pthread mutex. But in my case, I am not sure why/how a thread is trying to relock a mutex it already owns.

Comment: @AbhilashAnand You wait if the queue *was* empty. Not if the queue *is* empty. Your `run` function does not hold the mutex all the way from testing the queue to deciding to wait! (After `fetchNext` releases the mutex, you call `wait`, having no idea if the queue is still empty or if the add has already happened.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz. Apologies for the delayed response. So, do you recommend acquiring the mutex before the call to "fetchNext" and releasing it after the condvar wait()? Do you think this has any relation with the deadlock errors?

Comment: @AbhilashAnand The whole point of a condition variable is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" function so that you don't wait for something that has already happened. Misusing a condition variable will definitely lead to deadlock. Maybe you didn't really want a condition variable though.

Comment: The deadlock issue disappeared after I removed the condition if ( wasEmpty ) around the condvar.post(). No segmentation fault. That's good news. Thanks both. But it still happens to be crashing without a memory fault. Seems like an other issue.

Comment: @G.M.This is the comment against "lock" function in wrapperMutex "**This method locks a mutex. If the mutex is already locked the calling thread is blocked.**". So, in this case where the calling thread is blocked if the mutex is not obtained, is there still a possibility where the non thread safe queue is accessed in this scenario.

Comment: @G.M. Any comments on the above query? Apologies on the repeated question.

Comment: Well, in `CTraceFileWriterThread::fetchNext` you still have `if (!writeQueue.empty())` without having first acquired the mutex.

Comment: Yes. Apart from that, just confirming about accessing the queue when the lock is not obtained. You informed that I might be accessing the queue when the lock may not really be obtained. But the calling thread is blocked when the lock is not obtained. Do you think it is still an issue?