# QNX - core dump not getting generated on crash

Tags: c++, coredump, qnx

My multithreaded application is crashing randomly and a core dump is not getting generated which is making my analysis very very difficult. I have the **ulimit** set to **unlimited** and I have the **dumper** running. I see a signal 11 generated on crash which should have ideally generated a coredump.

I have had coredumps generated before for prior issues on the same system.
Note:
- directory has appropriate permissions.
- exe has the required permissions.

OS used - QNX
 Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the output to a log file?  Which version of QNX are you using?

Comment: Yes. I have placed extensive printf's in the program but those are not helping at all. It is not consistent.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004239/qnx-pthread-mutex-lock-causing-deadlock-error-45-edeadlk  for the code. I have resolved the issue in that question and this is the next issue.

Comment: @SPlatten, we are on QNX 6.5.0. Apologies, I missed your question before.

Answer (score 0):

I got the core-dump generated by manually adding a call to abort() in a function which i knew would be called when a signal to terminate the process is sent.